# grid.draw continue printing table into next page

Tags: r, gridextra

I have a `data.frame` of 60 rows. I am not able to print it in one pdf page. How can I continue printing it to next page ?

```
nr=2
nc=1
h=c(0.155,1)
Layout <- grid.layout(nrow=nr,ncol=nc,heights=unit(h, c("null")))
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = Layout))

print(Empty, vp = subplot(1, 1))

grid.draw(tableGrob(head(display_retail,15),
          show.rownames=F,cols=names,show.box=T,
          separator="black", gp=gpar(fontsize=6, lwd=2),
          vp = subplot(2, 1)))
```